# Particular integral of this 2nd order differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

$ d^2x/dt^2 - 4dx/dt = -8t $

I have found the auxiliary equation, being $ x(t) = A + Be^{4t} $ and consequently realised using the PI of the form

$ x = Ct + D $ would need updating.

In the solutions for the paper, they have updated it to

$ x = Ct^2 + Dt + E $

Why has the E constant been added on the end? Personally, I would have done $ x = Ct^2 + Dt $ which yields the same answer (Only given the certain situation with no x term in the DE)

What is the reason for the $+E$ constant at the end, of the new proposed PI? I was told when updating, all you need to do is multiply your PI by the independent variable. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter for this problem. Any constant is a solution of the homogeneous equation in this case. So you can absorb that $E$ factor there. No need to bother with it in the particular solution.

Comment: Say there was an X term though, would I need a +E?

Comment: Ask yourself why did you need to update the solution in the first place. Where did your $A$ term came from?

Comment: It came from $Ae^{0t}$, for the 0 root of the equation. How does this link to needing to update with an E? surely including the E would be bad since it matches the A in the Auxiliary equation

Comment: The fact that you have $e^0$ has two consequences. One of that is the $A$ term for the homogeneous equation, the other is the quadratic particular solution. It does not matter if the particular solution has or does not have the $E$ term. You are getting a constant anyway from the homogeneous solution. So the only thing that you can calculate from some initial conditions is the $A+E$ term.